# Stubbed method return value isn't being returned

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, stub, stubbing

I have stubbed a method and asked it to return a specific value. However when running the unit tests the real method gets called and returns a real value generated value.

i.e I stubbed the method get_requisition_number to return the value `1`, but when executing the unit tests it returns the value `2011031100001`

Unit Test Code:

```
it "should have a unique requisition number when saved" do 
  Requisition.stub(:get_requisition_number).and_return("1")
  req1 = Requisition.new
  req1.save
  req2 = Requisition.new
  lambda { req2.save! }.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError)
end
```

The method get_requisition_number is called when the save method is executed. I assume from the stub it should return `1`. However it returns a date specific value like `2011031100001`, which means it's running the actual method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub the method on the object instances, not the class.

```
req1 = Requisition.new
req1.stub(:get_requisition_number).and_return("1")
# same for req2
```

When you stub the class itself, you create a `get_requisition_number` method on the Requisition class, e.g. `Requisition.get_requisition_number`.

Comment: +1. thanks for the answer, I'm still pretty new to everything and that question had me baffled.